# Using same dish washer for meat and dairy?

Tags: halacha, meat-and-milk, appliances

Under what conditions can the same dish washer be used for washing both meat and dairy dishes?

Comment: http://www.torahmusings.com/2014/01/dishwashers-and-kashrut/

Comment: My Rabbi said that you can use the same dishwasher for meat and dairy dishes, since the cleaning process does something that renders it all OK.  (I don't remember the details, and I don't have source, and I'm not sure if you can wash both dishes at once... Otherwise I'd put this as an answer.)